# STM32F103 reading value from lightsensor by I2C

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal-library

I'm trying to read value from sensor GY-30 BH1750 by I2C but when I check variables in STM Studio, they don't change.

Sensor address is 0x23 when addr connected to GND

POWER_ON 0x01

RESET 0x07

BH1750_CONTINUOUS_HIGH_RES_MODE  0x10

It's my code which I try to get data :

```
 buffer[0] = BH1750_POWER_ON;
 buffer[1] = RESET;
 HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, SENSOR_ADDRESS << 1, buffer, 2, 100);
 buffer[0] = BH1750_CONTINUOUS_HIGH_RES_MODE;
 HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, SENSOR_ADDRESS << 1, buffer, 1, 100);
 HAL_Delay(180);
 HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, SENSOR_ADDRESS << 1, buffer, 2, 100);
```

Docs: http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/Digital%20light%20Sensor/bh1750fvi-e.pdf

What's wrong with code ? 
Thanks for help.

Comment: OK what's the question

Comment: Is that everything correct in code and it's problem with connections between stm32 and sensor or it's code problem ?
Sorry for that but Im new with stm

Answer (score 1):

Yes this answer is quite late. But...no one else answered this and I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with sending 2 commands simultaneously (and not checking return values for success on function calls doesn't help either). From what I can tell, you cannot send the BH1750_POWER_ON command and the RESET command at the same time (they are not a single command). Also, asynchronous reset is different then the Reset command. The data sheet says the following for RESET (datasheet version 2011.11 - Rev.D page 5):

....... Reset command is for only reset Illuminance data register. ( reset value is '0' ) It is not necessary even power supply sequence .......

Which basically means it doesn't really do much for the user. If you fail a read, you should get an error back. So resetting the data register to '0' won't help to determine if some other problem is occurring. Also, for powering on the device, I have notice a slight delay after sending the command helps the device perform as expected. I've inserted a HAL_Delay(5) after the power on command because of this.

So if the user still wants to use the RESET command, the initialization code would need to be modified as follows:

```
// Variables
const uint8_t nAddress = (SENSOR_ADDRESS << 1);
uint16_t nLUX = 0;
uint8_t pBuffer = (uint8_t*)&nLUX;  // So LUX value doesn't have to be recombined

// Power On
pBuffer[0] = BH1750_POWER_ON;
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nAddress, pBuffer, 1, 100) != HAL_OK)
   return false;
HAL_Delay(5);

// Reset Illuminance Register
pBuffer[0] = RESET;
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nAddress, pBuffer, 1, 100) != HAL_OK)
   return false;

// Set measurement mode
pBuffer[0] = BH1750_CONTINUOUS_HIGH_RES_MODE;
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nAddress, pBuffer, 1, 100) != HAL_OK)
   return false;
HAL_Delay(180); // Wait for measurement (or come back after 180 ms instead of idling)

// Read measurement
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, nAddress, pBuffer, 2, 100) != HAL_OK)
   return false;

// nLUX holds your LUX value now...
return true;
```

Or the version without the RESET

```
// Variables
const uint8_t nAddress = (SENSOR_ADDRESS << 1);
uint16_t nLUX = 0;
uint8_t pBuffer = (uint8_t*)&nLUX;  // So LUX value doesn't have to be recombined

// Power On
pBuffer[0] = BH1750_POWER_ON;
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nAddress, pBuffer, 1, 100) != HAL_OK)
   return false;
HAL_Delay(5);

// Set measurement mode
pBuffer[0] = BH1750_CONTINUOUS_HIGH_RES_MODE;
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, nAddress, pBuffer, 1, 100) != HAL_OK)
   return false;
HAL_Delay(180); // Wait for measurement (or come back after 180 ms instead of idling)

// Read measurement
if (HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, nAddress, pBuffer, 2, 100) != HAL_OK)
   return false;

// nLUX holds your LUX value now...
return true;
```

One other note, the large delay after sending in the BH1750_CONTINUOUS_HIGH_RES_MODE isn't necessary after the first read and can be closer to the 120ms time instead. A secondary function that basically checks if 120ms has elapsed since the last read is all that is necessary before another read can be performed (without any other commands sent).

```
const uint8_t nAddress = (SENSOR_ADDRESS << 1);
uint16_t nLUX = 0;
HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, nAddress, (uint8_t*)&nLUX, 2, 100);
```